# Default starting values fitting logistic regression with glm

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I'm wondering how are default starting values specified in `glm`.

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33857/initial-values-for-logistic-regression-using-maximum-likelihood) suggests that default values are set as zeros. This [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58670/starting-coefficient-vector-for-glm) says that there is an algorithm behind it, however relevant link is broken.

I tried to fit simple logistic regression model with algorithm trace:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(100)
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-x))
y <- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = p)

# to see parameter estimates in each step
trace(glm.fit, quote(print(coefold)), at = list(c(22, 4, 8, 4, 19, 3)))
```

First, without specification of initial values:

```
glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial")

Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
NULL
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.386379 1.106234
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3991135 1.1653971
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3995188 1.1669508
```

In the first step, initial values are `NULL`.

Second, I set starting values to be zeros:

```
glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial", start = c(0, 0))

Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0 0
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3177530 0.9097521
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3909975 1.1397163
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3994147 1.1666173
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3995191 1.1669518
```

And we can see that iterations between first and second approach differ.

To see initial values specified by `glm` I tried to fit model with only one iteration:

```
glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial", control = list(maxit = 1))

Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
NULL

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x, family = "binomial", control = list(maxit = 1))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.3864       1.1062  

Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  98 Residual
Null Deviance:      134.6 
Residual Deviance: 115  AIC: 119
```

Estimates of parameters (not surprisingly) correspond to estimates of the first approach in the second iteration i.e., `[1] 0.386379 1.106234`
Setting these values as initial values leads to the same iterations sequence as in the first approach:

```
glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial", start = c(0.386379, 1.106234))

Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.386379 1.106234
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3991135 1.1653971
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] 0.3995188 1.1669508
```

So the question is, how these values are calculated?

Comment: It's complicated. If you supply `start` values, they are used in the calculation of what gets passed to the `C_Cdqrls` routine. If you don't, the values that are passed get calculated (including a call `eval(binomial()$initialize)`), but `glm.fit` never explicitly calculates values for `start`. Take an hour or two and study the `glm.fit` code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to study `glm.fit` code but I still have no clue how the initial values are calculated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

- `start=c(b0,b1)` initializes eta to `b0+x*b1` (mu to 1/(1+exp(-eta)))
- `start=c(0,0)` initializes eta to 0 (mu to 0.5) regardless of y or x value.
- `start=NULL` initializes eta= 1.098612 (mu=0.75) if y=1, regardless of x value.
- `start=NULL` initializes eta=-1.098612 (mu=0.25) if y=0, regardless of x value.
- Once eta (and consequently mu and var(mu)) has been calculated, `w` and `z` are calculated and sent to a QR solver, in the spirit of `qr.solve(cbind(1,x) * w, z*w)`.

### Longform

Building off Roland's comment:  I made a `glm.fit.truncated()`, where I took `glm.fit` down to the `C_Cdqrls` call, and then commented it out.  `glm.fit.truncated` outputs the `z` and `w` values (as well as the values of the quantities used to calculate `z` and `w`) which would then be passed to the `C_Cdqrls` call:

```
## call Fortran code via C wrapper
fit <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x[good, , drop = FALSE] * w, z * w,
             min(1e-7, control$epsilon/1000), check=FALSE)
```

More can be read about `C_Cdqrls` [here](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2016/07/20/lm-in-R.html).  Luckily, the function `qr.solve` in base R taps directly into the LINPACK versions being called upon in `glm.fit()`.

So we run `glm.fit.truncated` for the different starting value specifications, and then do a call to `qr.solve` with the w and z values, and we see how the "starting values" (or the first displayed iteration values) are calculated.  As Roland indicated, specifying `start=NULL` or `start=c(0,0)` in glm() affects the calculations for w and z, *not* for `start`.

For the start=NULL:  `z` is a vector where the elements have the value 2.431946 or -2.431946 and `w` is a vector where all elements are 0.4330127:

```
start.is.null <- glm.fit.truncated(x,y,family=binomial(), start=NULL)
start.is.null
w <- start.is.null$w
z <- start.is.null$z
## if start is NULL, the first displayed values are:
qr.solve(cbind(1,x) * w, z*w)  
# > qr.solve(cbind(1,x) * w, z*w)  
#                 x 
# 0.386379 1.106234
```

For the start=c(0,0):  `z` is a vector where the elements have the value 2 or -2 and `w` is a vector where all elements are 0.5:

```
## if start is c(0,0)    
start.is.00 <- glm.fit.truncated(x,y,family=binomial(), start=0)
start.is.00
w <- start.is.00$w
z <- start.is.00$z
## if start is c(0,0), the first displayed values are:    
qr.solve(cbind(1,x) * w, z*w)  
# > qr.solve(cbind(1,x) * w, z*w)  
#                   x 
# 0.3177530 0.9097521
```

So that's all well and good, but how do we calculate the `w` and `z`? Near the bottom of `glm.fit.truncated()` we see

```
z <- (eta - offset)[good] + (y - mu)[good]/mu.eta.val[good]
w <- sqrt((weights[good] * mu.eta.val[good]^2)/variance(mu)[good])
```

Look at the following comparisons between the outputted values of the quantities used to calculate `z` and `w`:

```
cbind(y, start.is.null$mu, start.is.00$mu)
cbind(y, start.is.null$eta, start.is.00$eta)
cbind(start.is.null$var_mu, start.is.00$var_mu)
cbind(start.is.null$mu.eta.val, start.is.00$mu.eta.val)
```

Note that `start.is.00` will have vector `mu` with only the values 0.5 because eta is set to 0 and mu(eta) = 1/(1+exp(-0))= 0.5.  `start.is.null` sets those with y=1 to be mu=0.75 (which corresponds to eta=1.098612) and those with y=0 to be mu=0.25 (which corresponds to eta=-1.098612), and thus the `var_mu` = 0.75*0.25 = 0.1875.

However, it is interesting to note, that I changed the seed and reran everything and the mu=0.75 for y=1 and mu=0.25 for y=0 (and thus the other quantities stayed the same).  That is to say, start=NULL gives rise to the same `w` and `z` regardless of what `y` and `x` are, because they initialize eta=1.098612 (mu=0.75) if y=1 and eta=-1.098612 (mu=0.25) if y=0.

So it appears that a starting value for the Intercept coefficient and for the X-coefficient is not set for start=NULL, but rather initial values are given to eta depending on the y-value and independent of the x-value.  From there `w` and `z` are calculated, then sent along with `x` to the qr.solver.

### Code to run *before* the chunks above:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(100)
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-x))
y <- rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = p)


glm.fit.truncated <- function(x, y, weights = rep.int(1, nobs), 
start = 0,etastart = NULL, mustart = NULL, 
offset = rep.int(0, nobs),
family = binomial(), 
control = list(), 
intercept = TRUE,
singular.ok = TRUE
){
control <- do.call("glm.control", control)
x <- as.matrix(x)
xnames <- dimnames(x)[[2L]]
ynames <- if(is.matrix(y)) rownames(y) else names(y)
conv <- FALSE
nobs <- NROW(y)
nvars <- ncol(x)
EMPTY <- nvars == 0
## define weights and offset if needed
if (is.null(weights))
  weights <- rep.int(1, nobs)
if (is.null(offset))
  offset <- rep.int(0, nobs)

## get family functions:
variance <- family$variance
linkinv  <- family$linkinv
if (!is.function(variance) || !is.function(linkinv) )
  stop("'family' argument seems not to be a valid family object", call. = FALSE)
dev.resids <- family$dev.resids
aic <- family$aic
mu.eta <- family$mu.eta
unless.null <- function(x, if.null) if(is.null(x)) if.null else x
valideta <- unless.null(family$valideta, function(eta) TRUE)
validmu  <- unless.null(family$validmu,  function(mu) TRUE)
if(is.null(mustart)) {
  ## calculates mustart and may change y and weights and set n (!)
  eval(family$initialize)
} else {
  mukeep <- mustart
  eval(family$initialize)
  mustart <- mukeep
}
if(EMPTY) {
  eta <- rep.int(0, nobs) + offset
  if (!valideta(eta))
    stop("invalid linear predictor values in empty model", call. = FALSE)
  mu <- linkinv(eta)
  ## calculate initial deviance and coefficient
  if (!validmu(mu))
    stop("invalid fitted means in empty model", call. = FALSE)
  dev <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
  w <- sqrt((weights * mu.eta(eta)^2)/variance(mu))
  residuals <- (y - mu)/mu.eta(eta)
  good <- rep_len(TRUE, length(residuals))
  boundary <- conv <- TRUE
  coef <- numeric()
  iter <- 0L
} else {
  coefold <- NULL
  eta <-
    if(!is.null(etastart)) etastart
  else if(!is.null(start))
    if (length(start) != nvars)
      stop(gettextf("length of 'start' should equal %d and correspond to initial coefs for %s", nvars, paste(deparse(xnames), collapse=", ")),
           domain = NA)
  else {
    coefold <- start
    offset + as.vector(if (NCOL(x) == 1L) x * start else x %*% start)
  }
  else family$linkfun(mustart)
  mu <- linkinv(eta)
  if (!(validmu(mu) && valideta(eta)))
    stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some", call. = FALSE)
  ## calculate initial deviance and coefficient
  devold <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
  boundary <- conv <- FALSE
  
  ##------------- THE Iteratively Reweighting L.S. iteration -----------
  for (iter in 1L:control$maxit) {
    good <- weights > 0
    varmu <- variance(mu)[good]
    if (anyNA(varmu))
      stop("NAs in V(mu)")
    if (any(varmu == 0))
      stop("0s in V(mu)")
    mu.eta.val <- mu.eta(eta)
    if (any(is.na(mu.eta.val[good])))
      stop("NAs in d(mu)/d(eta)")
    ## drop observations for which w will be zero
    good <- (weights > 0) & (mu.eta.val != 0)
    
    if (all(!good)) {
      conv <- FALSE
      warning(gettextf("no observations informative at iteration %d",
                       iter), domain = NA)
      break
    }
    z <- (eta - offset)[good] + (y - mu)[good]/mu.eta.val[good]
    w <- sqrt((weights[good] * mu.eta.val[good]^2)/variance(mu)[good])
    # ## call Fortran code via C wrapper
    # fit <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x[good, , drop = FALSE] * w, z * w,
    #              min(1e-7, control$epsilon/1000), check=FALSE)
    # 
    
    #print(iter)
    #print(z)
    #print(w)
  }

  
  }
  return(list(z=z, w=w, mustart=mustart, etastart=etastart, eta=eta, offset=offset, mu=mu, mu.eta.val=mu.eta.val,
              weight=weights, var_mu=variance(mu)))

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, this is much beyond I was hoping for :)